# Why my WAMPSERVER can't work?

Tags: wampserver

I have some problem with my `WAMP` server and I downloaded from the official website. I wanted to use only for the local server (for Chrome), without WordPress, only for HTML/CSS/JS files. The servers (Apache, PHP and MySql) and the `localhost` webpage has оpen, but when I try to open my projects it's giving me the error:

> This webpage is not available ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED: and in details:
>   The server at problem%201 can't be found, because the DNS lookup
>   failed. DNS is the network service that translates a website's name to
>   its Internet address. This error is most often caused by having no
>   connection to the Internet or a misconfigured network. It can also be
>   caused by an unresponsive DNS server or a firewall preventing Google
>   Chrome from accessing the network.

P.S. OS: Windows 8.1 Pro N

Comment: Where are your projects and how do you try and run them i.e. what do you enter into the browser address bar

Comment: Thank you for answer me! :) I have already fixed. But I have another problem with Livereload and in particular with Firefox. When I install the add-on in Firefox, the icon in the browser isn't shown?                                   P.S. Firefox version is 43.0.4, Livereload - 2.1.1

Comment: Well post your own answer to this question, you can even except it and get reputation point for it. Otherwise the question is of no use to any other visitors. Then ask another question with all the relevant details please

Comment: Okey. I'm sorry for that and I will have it in mind. :)